# How to determine the boundedness for sequence $\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, boundary-value-problem

So apparently $\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and when $n=1$, the sequence is $0$. So it is bounded below by $0$. But how can you sure about the upper bound?

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}\leq \frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}\leq 2$.

Comment: Perhaps a little simpler: $\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}\leq \frac{n+1}{n}\leq \frac{n+n}{n} = 2$

Comment: The answer is $\frac{2}{3}$, but I don't know how the book gets it.

Comment: Are you sure? When $n=2$, $\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n}=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: My fault. It's $\frac32$